# How could Jolyne hold Goo Goo Dolls?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

[image]

I'm pretty sure that it was specifically stated that stands cannot be touched by people.

Did I get something wrong or is it just a mistake?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to your question.

1 Goo-Goo dolls is a stand that can be interacted with like strength. (Jotaro has been seen damaging the ship.)

2 This is the most likely answer, Jolyne's stand is two things. It is both a physical stand made out of string and the fact that her own body is made of string/ her body can turn into strings. This in a way makes her, her own stand, letting her grip goo-goo dolls.